# minimize f(x1,x2,..xn) with x1+x2+...+xn=C

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a non-linear and computationally costly function `f` which takes a set of variables `x1, x2, ... xn` with the constraint that the variables are positive floats and their sum equals a constant.

```
Minimize f(x1, x2, ..., xn)
x1 + x2 + ... + xn = C
xi > 0 for all i
```

I have used `scipy.optimize` module in the past in problems where I did not have the summation constraint. I am looking for any suggestions or pointers that could be of help.

The function is `f` is non-linear and takes significant time to compute. I don't have access to `f` (supplied by external vendor). `f` varies smoothly with each of `x`.

Comment: Please specify function f. If it is convex, then I suggest cvxpy.

Comment: Hennich - I updated the question with more details. I am reading to see if `f` could be called `convex`

Comment: scipy.minimize can still optimize this locally-optimal (SLSQP supports equality constraints). You can also implement a relative simple projected-gradient method. But using 2-order information in some way is probably a better idea given slow func-evals -> projected quasi-newton. (the projected variants are good ideas if projection is cheap compared to func-eval; your projection onto the *probability-simplex* is cheap)

Comment: sascha - would you recommend a book/reference that is simple to read and introduces these concepts for a non-mathematician ...

Comment: I would say: start with scipy.minimize first. Then: Numerical Optimization (Nocedal) for a very general overview and every paper/slides from [Mark Schmidt](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/) who did a lot in regards to projected quasi-newton methods including a lot of nice to read high-quality open-source code (matlab!; at least most parts are nice to read). *Remark:* i earlier said probability-simplex; it's actually the positive-simplex). *How big is N?*

Comment: N is usually around 5, can go up to 20. In same case f can take as much as 20mins to few hours for one evaluation.

Comment: That sounds bad. As nice as PQN-methods are, without a clear idea of the function you would need numerical-differentiation which uses (many costly) additional function-calls. This is probably more a problem for zero-order / derivative-free optimization-methods. Library-support is probably more sparse there, especially with support for constraints (i'm guessing). The func-eval time-variance makes me also wonder if it's some kind of monte-carlo simulation. In this case noise can hurt too (less for derivative-free methods).